# String Formatting for a list

Tags: java, output-formatting

I'm making a shopping list using data from a CSV file. I've run to a roadblock around the output formatting. I'm not very familiar with java, as I'm brand new to coding. I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to line up my headers with the information below it. right now it is outputting like this:

```
Item Category Amount Price Location
Apple Food 12 1 Walmart
Grapes Food 15 0.5 Walmart
```

I want it to output like this:

```
Item  | Category | Amount | Price | Location
Apple |  Food    |   12   |   1   | Walmart
Grapes|  Food    |   15   |  0.5  | Walmart
```

my code so far is looking like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList <Caring> csvstuff = new ArrayList <Caring> ();
    String fileName = "Project2.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
            String data = inputStream.next();
            String[] values = data.split(",");
            String Item = values[0];
            String Category = values[1];
            String Amount = values[2];
            String Price = values[3];
            String Location = values[4];
            System.out.println(values[0] + " " + values[1] + " " + values[2] + " " + values[3] + " " + values[4]);
            caring _caring = new caring(Item, Category, Amount, Price, Location);
            csvstuff.add(_caring);
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into how to format strings? Right now you're just printing out what you have with single space separators.

Comment: If you're able to use `StringUtils` (apache commons) then it has methods for left, center and right justifying within a fixed width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String format for this.

```
String format = "%-10s |%10s |%10s |%10s |%10s\n";
System.out.printf(format, values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4]);
```

above code will give the expected result.

EDIT: Using StringUtils for formatting.

```
String result = StringUtils.EMPTY;
result = StringUtils.center(values[0], 10) + '|' + StringUtils.center(values[1], 10) + '|'+ StringUtils.center(values[2], 15) + '|' + StringUtils.center(values[3], 15) + '|'
+ StringUtils.center(values[4], 15);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: It looks like OP wants values centred `String.format` does not support centre justification

Comment: Thnks @sprinter yeah string.format doesnt support justification. We could use StringUtils in that case.